# Count number of rows with data in all tables whose names contain @

Tags: php, mysql

I want to count the rows with data in all tables which contain the symbol @ in their name. Code I wrote returns 429 rows for each table and that is not the correct value.

Here is the code:

```
<?php

$showtables = mysqli_query($conn, "SHOW TABLES FROM codecleanup like '%@%'");
$total = 0;
while ($table = mysqli_fetch_array($showtables)) { // go through each row that was returned in $result
    //  echo($table[0] . "<br>");    // print the table that was returned on that row.
    $trenutnatabela = $table[0];
    //echo "trenutna tabela je:" .   $trenutnatabela;

    $upittrentabela = "SELECT * FROM '$trenutnatabela'";
    $rezultattrentabela = mysqli_query($conn, $upittrentabela);
    $rows_count_value = mysqli_num_rows($rezultattrentabela);
    //echo $rows_count_value;
    $total = $total + $rows_count_value;
}
echo "Total number of records is " . $total;
```

I tried to loop through table names, count all rows with data in each table and sum up the number of rows with data.

Comment: Have you checked that the annotated echoes show the expected table names?

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32391315)

Answer (score 2):

Use this query:

```
SELECT
    TABLE_NAME,
    SUM(TABLE_ROWS)
FROM
    information_schema.tables
WHERE
    TABLE_SCHEMA = 'codecleanup' AND TABLE_NAME LIKE '%@%';
```